# PHP Symfony Swift_Mailer error: # unable to fetch the response from the backend: malformed MIME header: missing colon: %!!(MISSING)q(MISSING)#5 {main}

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, localhost, swiftmailer

I have just started using Swiftmailer in Symfony5. The problem is that when I run this with Symfony on localhost server to send email, it throws error as above.

```
                $transport
                    ->setUsername("mygmail@gmail.com")
                    ->setPassword("pass");

                $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

                $message = new Swift_Message();
                $message
                    ->setFrom("mygmail@gmail.com")
                    ->setTo("mygmail@gmail.com")
                    ->setSubject("title")
                    ->setBody("body of swift mailer");

                $mailer->send($message);
```

config_dev.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
  transport: gmail
  username: mygmail@gmail.com
  password: (my google app password)
```

php.ini:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_from = mateuszwlecial03@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header = Off
```

sendmail.ini:

```
smtp_server = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
error_logfile = error.log
debug_logfile = debug.log
auth_username = mygmail@gmail.com
auth_password = (my google app password)
force_sender = mygmail@gmail.com
smtp_ssl=auto
```

I couldn't find that issue anywhere. Any ideas what can be reason of this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, updating the global verison of symfony solved this. Just run `symfony self-update` and make sure everything is up to date.